# Ajax generated content and Facebook scraping

Tags: ajax, facebook, .htaccess, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I've built an AngularJS app and it contains views that could be considered different pages but the app is a single page app as in the page doesn't reload.

I've read up on using escaped fragment URLs to redirect search engines to snapshots of pages. My issue is when I try to share a page from my app on Facebook that it returns a 404, as can be seen using [Facebook's open graph debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/).

My app has a Larvel back-end feeding to an AngularJS front-end and my htaccess looks like this to redirect spiders and Facebook to the snapshots. As far as I knew this was working but I guess it's not.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [NC,PT]

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My URLS are formatted to the user like: domain.com/#!/bike/id/bike+name
and the snapshot URLs are the same just without the hash bang i.e domain.com/bike/id/bike+name

I'm really stunmped on this one. Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook crawlers don't execute any Javascript so they won't see/have no idea about your Angular routes. What I've done in my project is I've mirrored the routes that need the open-graph tags in the back-end.

If my server gets a request for a page with og-tags it will make the necessary API calls to get the data, and attach them to the index template. If my initial request is the a page with no og-tags, I just render the regular SPA index. (I'm using HTML5 mode for urls so could be a bit different for you)

Also note that I said **initial** request to the server. This means that your og-tags won't change as you navigate within your SPA, they'll just be the tags of the first page you requested. This is actually a non-issue because Facebook makes individuals request to your server.

Let me know if this is unclear, I'll try to explain better.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're already trying something similar in your back-end (don't know Larvel, I use NodeJS/Express). In any case, this problem has to be solved in the back-end, not with Angular.

Comment: I think I get you. I'm tryinh to do the same but since I'm using #! URLs I'm probably trying to do it slightly differently. So you don't need to redirect bots to the server side page since you're using pretty much the same URL stucture and the crawlers get sent to the server generated pages, right?

Comment: Yea you just need to figure out a way for your server to interpret the `#!/bike/id/bike+name` part of your url when a user makes the initial request

Comment: Cool thank you, I'm trying to do that in my .htaccess but it doesn't seem to be working after all.